# Drawer slide catching can’t remove

Tags: screws, drawers

The drawer slide won’t extend fully because it keeps getting caught. I think it is catching on a loose screw but I can’t access the screw to tighten it as the slide keeps getting caught! Does anyone know how I can remove the slide when I don’t have access to the screws(because it won’t slide past the back ones as it keeps getting caught on them). Very frustrating.

[image]

Comment: Is the slide completely stuck in the spot it's in right now, or will it slide some, but not all the way in/out? If it will move some, you _may_ be able to slide the openings in the moving part over all the screw heads. I presume you tried that before asking, but just checking to be sure.

Comment: Might be able to use a screw driver to carefully nudge it over the head/s.  Do not force but try to separate/increase distance between the two pieces.

Comment: With whatever travel you have available on it, move it back and forth and watch and feel vibrations until you're fairly certain exactly what is stuck.  I can see at least 1 screw through the rail, so you may be able to tighten it or other screws to slide past them.  With some of that type of rail, the center rail can be removed and re-inserted in place by pressing or prying a release and pulling it out the end, so thoroughly examine it.  If you think you know where a problem screw is but you can't slide it far enough to see it through the holes, be aware you can drill additional holes.

Comment: If the slider part with the bearings is stuck, again, carefully examine it and how much it moves.  Bearings can be jammed by tiny objects.

Comment: Wohoo thanks team!! Got it by using the screwdriver method - crip659. Thanks to all four of you for taking the time to help me out. Appreciate it.